# Karma get scope of Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am using karma to load an angular directive (with the html2js plugin):

```
beforeEach(module('partials/myDir.html'));

beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $compile, $rootScope){
    $gCompile = $compile;
             $gScope = $rootScope;

}));

it("test test", function() {
    element = $gCompile('<my-dir></my-dir>')($gScope);
    $gScope.$digest();
    console.log($gScope);
});
```

This all works fine, what I now want to do is access the directives scope from the $rootScope object injected in the beforeEach.

Comment: If you want to access the element's scope, you can use `element.scope()` or `element.isolateScope()`.

Comment: I don't understand, your `$gScope` is compiled, digested... what do you want more? :)

Answer (score 4):

It depends upon your directive definition object. I don't see one in your question so I will answer for all three options.

**Defining Scope or Child Scope:**
This would be set by either doing `scope: true` or using the default scope value, which is false.

```
 element.scope()
```

**Isolate Scope:**

This would be used if an Isolate Scope is created by your directive.

```
 element.IsolateScope()
```